# boost::shared_array<char> to std::string

Tags: c++, string, boost

What is the best way to convert a `boost::shared_array<char>` to a `std::string`?
The following snippet works but it does not look very elegant.

```
boost::shared_array<char> boostString = DatabaseFileName.GetCString(CZString::eAscii);
std::string stdString;
for(size_t i = 0; boostString[i] != 0; i++)
{
    stdString.append(1, boostString[i]);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout following code. This will give you clear idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost\shared_array.hpp>

void main()
{   
    char *ptr = "mystring" ;
    boost::shared_array<char> myIntArray(new char[strlen(ptr) + 1]);
    strncpy(myIntArray.get(), ptr, strlen(ptr) + 1);
    std::string str(myIntArray.get());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Boost shared array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) uses `new[]` to allocate its data, which means it's all contiguous in memory. That means you can get a pointer to the first element as a C-style string, from which you can create a `std::string` instance.

This of course requires the data to either have a terminator, or for you to know the length of the "string".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to futz around with `strncpy` and worrying of the `boost::shared_array<char>` is null-terminated, you can write (assuming `boostString` and `stdString` from the original example:

```
std::copy(boostString.begin(), boostString.end(),
    std::back_inserter<std::string>(stdString));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to "Some Programmer dude"'s answer I coded the solution.
Please notice that the `boostString` string is zero-terminated.

```
boost::shared_array<char> boostString = str.GetCString(CZString::eAscii);
std::string stdStr(boostString.get());
```